# Azure/Azure-AD Subscription for Power BI

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I planning for Power BI Implementation for one of the customers (With 800 Users), they do not have azure subscription nor Azure AD! How shall I get it started? Do I need to ask the customer to Subscribe to Azure? Will the free-tier of Azure AD work? What all the pre-requisites, Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Azure active directory subscription comes for free if you have a paid azure, office 365 , Dynamics CRM subscriptions. You can go register for it and use it. 
If the company already uses office 365 then it is  quite easy to integrate with powerbi apps. 
If azure active directory is the option you can add users or sync local AD users and integrate with Powerbi. You can also setup ADFS for a single sign-on option.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-active-directory-and-power-bi/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832618.aspx